# WPF MVVM: EventTrigger is not working inside CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm, eventtrigger

I'm building an application with WPF in MVVM style. I'm trying to make filter on my `DataGrid` when I check or uncheck several CheckBoxes for filtering.

I've found solution with `Interaction.Triggers`, but it's not working for me in this case.

Here is my code:

```
<ListBox 
            ItemsSource="{Binding PortsFilterSource}"
            Background="LightGray"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Grid.Column="1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox 
                        Content="{Binding Name}"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}">

                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FilterCommand}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FilterCommand}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Everything is working great except `FilterCommand`. I have this in my C# code:

```
public DelegateCommand<object> FilterCommand { get; set; }
...
FilterCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(Filter);
```

`Filter(object obj)` is a function, but it is not entered when I check or uncheck any of my CheckBoxes.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Why not using the setter of `IsChecked` to call `Filter`?

Comment: Look at the output window when debugging, do you have any binding errors?

Comment: Oh, yes, I have: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : `BindingExpression path error: 'FilterCommand' property not found on 'object' ''FilterModel' (HashCode=57774494)'. BindingExpression:Path=FilterCommand; DataItem='FilterModel' (HashCode=57774494); target element is 'InvokeCommandAction' (HashCode=8505800); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')`

Comment: @JanDotNet I have an object `FilterModel` in different file than `Filter` method. It cannot be static. Is there any other way to call it?

Comment: But the `FilterCommand` and the `IsChecked` properties are in the same class, isn't it`?

Comment: @ajg Do you have any solution to that error?

Comment: What is DelegateCommand, are you using prism?

Comment: @JanDotNet No. I have class `FilterModel` with 2 attributes - `Name` and `IsChecked`. `FilterModel` is `DelegateCommand` in `MainViewModel`

Comment: @ajg Yes, I'm using prism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that the data context of the list item is of type `FilterModel`, but the `FilterCommand` is in the parent view model.

Try the following binding for the command:

```
{Binding DataContext.FilterCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is work for me.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="IsApved"  IsReadOnly="False" CanUserSort="False" Width="55">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox 
                        Content="{Binding Name}"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsSelect,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).